# jSON is returning data starting from second request and not on first request

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to process a query and load jSON data on success. Here, the problem is that the jSON data is being returned successfully and gets displayed but starting from SECOND TIME. Yes, you read that right. I mean that when I press the submit button and the data gets processed for the 1st time via AJAX the jSON data return is not updated. But when I press the submit button 2nd time or 3rd time or 4th time or so on, the updated data gets displayed. Why its not working on the 1st time? Here I am trying to update the Wallet Balance and Table Data.

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card card-danger">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3 class="card-title">Request Pin</h3>
        </div>
        <form role="form" method="post" action="" name="requestPin">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Enter Amount (&#8377;)</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="1500" name="amount">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="requestPin" value="Request">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8 text-right">
                Wallet Balance: &#8377;<span id="wallet"><?php echo $bal['wal_balance']; ?></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="overlay">
          <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="message"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3 class="card-title">Request History</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
          <table class="table table-hover" id="pinReqHist">
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Amount</th>
              <th>Request Date</th>
              <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
              while($pin = $pinReq->fetch()){ extract($pin);
                if($pr_status == 'approved'){
                  $statusColor = "text-success";
                }else if($pr_status == 'denied'){
                  $statusColor = "text-danger";
                }else{
                  $statusColor = "text-warning";
                }
            ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $pr_id; ?></td>
                <td>&#8377;<?php echo $pr_amount; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo date('jS F, Y (h:i a)', strtotime($pr_date)); ?></td>
                <td><span class="<?php echo $statusColor; ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($pr_status); ?></span></td>
              </tr>
            <?php } ?>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

request-pin.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../config/db.php'); include('../functions.php');
$msg = null;
$userid = (!empty($_SESSION['loggedin']))?$_SESSION['loggedin']:null;

$amount = (!empty($_POST['amount']))?$_POST['amount']:null;

if($_POST){
  $balance = $pdo->prepare("SELECT wal_balance FROM wallet WHERE wal_user = :user");
  $balance-> bindValue(':user', $userid);
  $balance-> execute();
  $bal = $balance->fetch();

  $product = $pdo->prepare("SELECT pro_price FROM products
                            LEFT JOIN user_products ON products.pro_id = user_products.up_product
                            WHERE up_user = :user");
  $product-> bindValue(':user', $userid);
  $product-> execute();
  $pro = $product->fetch();

  if($amount == ''){
    $msg = "Amount is required.";
    echo json_encode(array('status' => alert_danger_dismiss($msg), 'bal' => number_format($bal['wal_balance'],2,'.',',')));
  }else if(!ctype_digit($amount)){
    $msg = "Please enter only numbers.";
    echo json_encode(array('status' => alert_danger_dismiss($msg), 'bal' => number_format($bal['wal_balance'],2,'.',',')));
  }else if($amount%$pro['pro_price'] != 0){
    $msg = "Please enter amount in multiples of your product price. For eg., if your product price is &#8377;500 then you can enter either &#8377;500 or &#8377;1000 or &#8377;1500 and so on.";
    echo json_encode(array('status' => alert_danger_dismiss($msg), 'bal' => number_format($bal['wal_balance'],2,'.',',')));
  }else{
    if($bal['wal_balance'] < $amount){
      $msg = "Insufficient balance.";
      echo json_encode(array('status' => alert_danger_dismiss($msg), 'bal' => number_format($bal['wal_balance'],2,'.',',')));
    }else{
      $insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO pin_request(pr_user, pr_amount)VALUES(:user, :amt)");
      $insert-> bindValue(':user', $userid);
      $insert-> bindValue(':amt', $amount);
      $insert-> execute();

      if($insert){
        $update = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE wallet SET wal_balance = wal_balance-".$amount." WHERE wal_user = :user");
        $update-> bindValue(':user', $userid);
        $update-> execute();

        $wallet = $pdo->prepare("SELECT wal_balance FROM wallet WHERE wal_user = :user");
        $wallet-> bindValue(':user', $userid);
        $wallet-> execute();
        $wal = $wallet->fetch();

        $pinReq = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pin_request WHERE pr_user = :user ORDER BY pr_id DESC");
        $pinReq-> bindValue(':user', $userid);
        $pinReq-> execute();

        $table = "<table class='table table-striped' id='pinReqHist'>
                    <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Amount</th>
                      <th>Request Date</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>";

        while($pin = $pinReq->fetch()){ extract($pin);
          if($pr_status == 'approved'){
            $statusColor = "text-success";
          }else if($pr_status == 'denied'){
            $statusColor = "text-danger";
          }else{
            $statusColor = "text-warning";
          }
          $table .= "<tr>
                      <td>".$pr_id."</td>
                      <td>&#8377;".$pr_amount."</td>
                      <td>".date("jS F, Y (h:i a)", strtotime($pr_date))."</td>
                      <td><span class='".$statusColor."'>".ucfirst($pr_status)."</span></td>
                    </tr>";
        }

        $table .= "</table>";

        $msg = "Pin request sent!";
        echo json_encode(array('status' => alert_success_dismiss($msg), 'bal' => number_format($wal['wal_balance'],2,'.',','),
                               'table' => $table));
      }else{
        $msg = "Server Error! Please try again.";
        echo json_encode(array('status' => alert_danger_dismiss($msg), 'bal' => number_format($bal['wal_balance'],2,'.',',')));
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Pin Request
    $("#requestPin").click(function() {
      var form = document.requestPin;
      var dataString = $(form).serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        url: "processes/request-pin.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: true,
        beforeSend: function(){
          $('.message').hide();
          $('.overlay').fadeIn();
        },
        success: function(json){
          if($('.message').find('#responseBox').hasClass('alert-success')){
            setTimeout(function(){
              $('#wallet').html(json.bal);
              $('#pinReqHist').html(json.table).fadeIn();
            }, 2000);
          }
          setTimeout(function(){
            $('.overlay').fadeOut();
            $('.message').html(json.status).fadeIn();
          }, 2000);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your data? What about you do some `console.log()`s in your Javascript? E.g. `console.log(json)` inside your success callback to see if data has actually been returned and if the callback is triggered.

Comment: Thanks @minitauros for taking out time for me. However, I have figured out the solution. Its was due to the way I had written my success function in jQuery. I will post the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. It was due to `$('.message')` getting delayed due to `setTimeOut()` function.

I had to take `$('.message')` out of the `setTimeOut()` function and initialize the jSON message to it outside. After that I displayed it inside the `setTimeOut()`  function as usual for the animation effect.

I had to change my success function from this

```
success: function(json){
  if($('.message').find('#responseBox').hasClass('alert-success')){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#wallet').html(json.bal);
      $('#pinReqHist').html(json.table).fadeIn();
    }, 2000);
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.overlay').fadeOut();
    $('.message').html(json.status).fadeIn();
  }, 2000);
}
```

to this

```
success: function(json){
  $('.message').html(json.status);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.overlay').fadeOut();
    $('.message').fadeIn();
  }, 2000);
  if($('.message').find('#responseBox').hasClass('alert-success')){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#wallet').html(json.bal);
      $('#pinReqHist').html(json.table).fadeIn();
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```